# How long would a 48 volt battery with 40 Ah last with a 2000 watt motor?

Tags: watts, volts

If it is not over 3 hours what would be good to make it last longer? I am trying to build a 48 volt dirt bike with 2000 watts.

Comment: It depends on the load on the motor.

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: It is a 48 volt motor and 2000 watts

Comment: I need to know how long a 48 volt battery would last with 40 ah in the battery. On a 48 volt motor at 2000 watts

Comment: It will last less than 1 hour.  2000 Watts divided by 48 Volts equals 41.6667 Amps. Power in Watts equals Volts times Current in Amps.

Comment: The motor's current consumption depends on the load. higher load, higher current (more effort).

Comment: Mike thank you how can I make the time higher like 4 hours

Comment: What do you guys mean it depends on the motor. Sorry I am only 14

Comment: If the motor is working hard, it will use more energy from the battery than if it's just coasting. A 2 kW motor most likely won't be running at 2 kW all the time. If the load *is* a constant 2 kW, all you can do to make the time longer is get a bigger battery (or more batteries).

Comment: A 2000W motor means that it can produce a maximum continuous power of 2000W, but usually wheeled vehicles aren't running like that all the time so the actual power used it a lot less on average. Situtations that use the most power are accelerating, and going up hills, and especially accelerating up hills. Rough terrain will also increase power draw.

Comment: You could probably do a guesstimate of how much power your motor will draw during normal use if you are willing to go through these calculations here:  https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31501/how-can-i-calculate-the-power-and-torque-required-for-the-motor-on-a-wheeled-rob Sounds like you need to do that anyways.

Comment: There is a chance it might last 3 hours. The reason nobody here can say for sure whether it will last for 3 hours is because it depends on how you ride it. It will for sure last 3 hours if you limit the top speed (or just ride more slowly). I work in the e-bike industry. Your battery pack is pretty big. You are not too far off track in what you are trying to do, but it is just going to be hard to give exact numbers because of all the variables.

Comment: Oh, I guess I should qualify this a bit. If you imagine it like an electric mountain bike, not going super fast and doing wheelies and burnouts, it may last 3 hours. If you imagine it like a 250cc Honda, just forget about it. The motor is not anywhere near powerful enough for that. What you have is a powerful electric mountain bike with a huge battery pack (compared to what is out there).

Comment: @Caleb You can use google for these calcs: (2000 watt)*(3 hours)/(48 volt) in amp-hour = 125 amp-hour. So you will need well *more* than that. Say 100% more?

Comment: @jonk You would not ride the bike with constant 2kW, just like you would not drive your car with full throttle. There might also be local legal requirements for e-bike speeds or power limits and exceeding those will make the bike illegal.

Comment: @Justme Just a simplistic, worst case. Mostly though, I was hoping to point out that google can do math. Not provide an accurate-for-situation answer.

Comment: Buddy your not funny I tried googling there not smart

Comment: Computing *battery loaded with a motor*, consider how both are specified. Electrical machine power values are *output* power: For input, divide by efficiency. Nominal battery capacity is *new, neither hot nor cold, at rated current* - to get high values, 20 or *10 hour discharge to a cut-off voltage that doesn't make life expectancy look bad* gets quoted. The battery's inner resistance turns some of the energy into heat, contributing to the discharge current limit: At higher currents, the energy supplied before cut-off is reduced. Expect about 40 min@2kW rather than 57, less with frost & age.

Comment: The battery voltage and its power drop as the battery discharges then the e-bike maximum speed and power also drop. Does the electronics disconnect the 48V Lithium battery when its voltage drops to about 34V to avoid destroying he battery?

Answer (score 7):

2000W is likely the maximum the motor can draw, not what it will be drawing all the time. If you can find the part number on the motor we can tell you more.

Even if you run at full throttle, it might not max out the motor depending on the design of the dirt bike, and the riding conditions.

But if it did the math would be simple...

48V * 40Ah = 1920Wh (watt hours)

1920Wh / 2000W = 0.96 hours

If you want it to last for 3 hours instead of 0.96 you could simply reduce the throttle from 100% to 32%

1920Wh / (2000W * 0.32) = 3h

That's the theoretical answer, which is probably not what you're looking for. The practical options to improve your ride times are:

- Use less throttle while riding
- Install a bigger battery
- Swap out components with more efficient versions (expect small gains here, like 20% tops)

Comment: What battery then

Comment: You would need to update your question with much more detail about your bikes electrical system for us to be able to answer that. We would want part numbers of all the parts as well as how they are connected (not a simple task I know).

Answer (score 5):

Some rough math. At full load, we have:

- 48V * 40Ah = **1920Wh**
- 1920Wh / 2000W = **0.98h**

So approximately **one hour** at full load assuming an average battery voltage of 48V and constant current (a bit over 41A).

In real life the time will be somewhat less than that. The battery voltage will decrease as it discharges. It will also heat up some, further increasing losses (battery cooling is a big issue for electric vehicles.) With this in mind, a conservative estimate would be about 80% of that figure, so about **48 minutes** at full draw.

Now let’s assume you limit the top speed to Class 2 or 3 e-bike (20mph or 28mph), which an off-the shelf e-bike controller normally will do. Real world power draw for a bike running at Class 2 or 3 e-bike speed would be much less, between 250 to 500W (1/3 to 2/3 HP) on level terrain, so run time would be correspondingly longer. That said, 48Ah is a *big* battery, so figure **3 hours or more with normal use**, and perhaps **over 100 miles range** on level ground.

That is, even if your motor *can* make 2000W, it isn’t going to be *making* 2000W unless you’re running a known, constant load like climbing a very long and steep hill. But in general, the slower you go, the longer your battery will last.

Here’s a sim tool for various e-bike systems, which can give you an idea of range vs. battery size: https://ebikes.ca/tools/simulator.html

Now, bear in mind that 2000W is a fair amount of power: 2.7 HP in fact. I’m going to make the leap and assume your interest is fitting such a motor as an upgrade to an e-bike (yea, I was 14 once, too.) 2000W is enough to propel an e-bike well over 30mph, [and maybe even as much as 40mph on level ground.](https://hpcbikes.com/products/black-lightning)

Sounds like fun? Yep. There may be a [Sur-Ron](https://www.surronracingusa.com/) in my future someday, which is built more like a motorcycle.

Now here’s where I harsh your mellow. That kind of speed would be for off-road use only (and good on you for noting that you want to make a 'dirt bike'); for on-road use it would be classed as a motorcycle and need a license to operate. [Even a Class 3 (28mph) e-bike is off limits to riders under age 16](https://bikexchange.com/electric-bike-rules-regulations/) in many places. I know, kind of a buzzkill, but there’s valid reasons for that.

Also know that a powerful e-bike like you're contemplating will be excluded from most MTB and mixed-use trails too (as are Class 3 e-bikes.)

Point being, if you build such a thing, treat it with respect and know your local laws so you can ride it legally and responsibly. Know before you go.

Finally, a word about safety.

Upgrading the power means that the whole bike is more stressed: frame, suspension, wheels and bearings, brakes, and especially the chain if you're doing mid-drive. In fact, 2000W is much, much more than bicycle chain can handle (the Sur-Ron uses a #420 motorcycle chain.) And the 48V/40Ah battery is much heavier too. Consider all this as you plan your build.

Also, consider that an electric bike can fail in some spectacular and dangerous ways unique to electric. They don't have clutches, and must rely on the controller to cut power. They also make max torque at near zero RPM. So if the motor sticks on it's very hard to control: no clutch to pull in, and you better hope the kill switch works and that you can get to it.

Cautionary tale. I have a good friend, a motorcycle mechanic, who was badly hurt test-riding an electric motorcycle after its controller firmware was re-flashed. The bike 'ran away' on him at full throttle, and the kill button didn't work, launching him straight into a semi.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the amperage, or load, of the motor. At 40ah, if your motor is drawing 10 amps, you will get 4 hours. If your motor is drawing 80 amps, you'll get 1/2 hour. As the amperage will vary, your run time will vary.